# Append the selected value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a javascript function for my project which will append the selected value on current value.
For example, I am using following code

```js
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
select.onchange = function() {
  input.value = select.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value="price1">blue</option>
    <option value="price2">green</option>
    <option value="price3">red</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="checkPrice()">
```

It displays one selected value.
I need to append selected value to previously selected value, if I select 'blue' first and then 'green', it should display "blue,green". If I select red after that, it should display "blue,green,red"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Java or Javascript? They are completely separate

Comment: i need a function using javascript

Comment: @UpendraJoshi: Get the value as described in the duplicate, then use `input.value +=`.

Comment: what if you select 'blue' first, 'green' second, 'red' third, and 'blue' again the fourth time? What should the text input display then? 'blue,green,red,blue'? just trying to understand. i'm assuming you need a javascript function

Comment: it should keep on adding values to textfield

Comment: @UpendraJoshi -  Code has been provided here - https://jsfiddle.net/efk8fmy8/6/

Comment: Looks like someone already provided the solution. You should mark it as accepted.

Comment: yes! got the solution! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the selected text as your requested.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = input.value + (input.value.length > 0 ? "," : "") + select.options[select.selectedIndex].text
}
```

```html
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value="price1">blue</option>
    <option value="price2">green</option>
    <option value="price3">red</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="checkPrice()">
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: yeah, i was just wondering about that too?. I voted the answer up..

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for the vote, I think someone downvoted because it been marked as a duplicate, but at the time I started to answer it was not. that's why I went through with it.

Comment: happens to me sometimes too.. annoying that!

Comment: @RachelGallen But hey, can't change it, if someone feels like downvoting it then fine. Thanks for your vote anyway.

Comment: always happy to vote up a good answer.. :)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks alot! it worked!

Comment: So, even though you _know_ it's a duplicate, you still go ahead and continue working on the answer... Sure, this answer works, it's correct and everything, we shouldn't be encouraging _no-research_ questions by answering them.

Comment: I searched but I didn't find what i wanted so i asked the question

Comment: @Cerbrus No, I didn't know it was an updated. I didn't notice the Duplicate mark before after I posted the answer.

Comment: Removing the answer is always an option.